# Self-organizing pattern of magnetic domains

Tags: magnetic-fields, models, complex-systems

I would like to model an structure like this:

[image]

using simple methods like cellular automata or networks.
The picture is signed as *"a self-organizing pattern of magnetic domains in cobalt"*.

I'm not a noob in physics; and  understand enough about magnetic domains.
But can not even imagine how this configuration could arise.

Articles on this topic are not available (or are very expensive).
I will be grateful for any ideas and references about the math
underlying such processes.

Comment: Is this the domain structure of a thin film? Bubble domains? Articles may be free on arxiv.org

Comment: Also, if allowed by your local legislation, there is [Sci-hub](http://ocean.sci-hub.tw/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific **figure** in the original post seems to originate from [design](https://patterns.architexturez.net/file/figure-one-geometry-resilience-nature-jpg) and [architecture](http://www.andrebonfanti.it/en/content/toward-resilient-architectures-4-geometry-resilience) publications, more specifically [books](https://books.google.de/books?id=LW3sDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT38&ots=rOoqPRJZJs&dq=%22a%20self-organizing%20pattern%20of%20magnetic%20domains%20in%20cobalt%22&pg=PT38#v=onepage&q=%22a%20self-organizing%20pattern%20of%20magnetic%20domains%20in%20cobalt%22&f=false) of questionable scientific rigorousness. The original source, though, seems to be a [paper from the 1950's](https://jphysrad.journaldephysique.org/articles/jphysrad/abs/1951/03/jphysrad_1951__12_3_308_0/jphysrad_1951__12_3_308_0.html) ([e-print](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00234388), Fig. 5b), and similar-looking pictures can be found in other publications as well (e.g., [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.54.3428) [[e-print](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michel_Hehn/publication/13303694_Nanoscale_magnetic_domain_structures_in_epitaxial_cobalt_films/links/558bdb2d08ae591c19d8d384.pdf)] or [this PhD dissertation](https://curate.nd.edu/show/qf85n873b3q) [[mirror](https://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/~montek/teaching/Comp790-Fall11/Home/Home_files/Imre-PhD-Thesis.pdf)]).

As for the **modeling**, i.e., how these patterns can form, it seems that:

- a short range ferromagnetism, and
- a longish range (e.g., $\propto r^{-3}$) at least partially anti-ferromagnetic interaction

are the essential ingredients: bubbles and stripes such as this have been shown to arise in ferromagnetic, nearest-neighbor Ising models with dipolar interactions ([paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.70.046204), [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0402406); [another paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmmm.2015.03.015)) as well as in spin 1 models with long-range interactions ([paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.65.064447), [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0110208), [e-print](http://www.fis.puc.cl/~mkiwi/CV90.pdf)).

With respect to **cellular automata** or similar models, magnetic-domain-like patterns certainly can be generated (see, e.g., [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0167-739X(99)00045-X) [[arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/comp-gas/9905001)] and [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/0378-4371(92)90277-W) [[e-print](https://kuldoc.com/download/two-types-of-performance-of-an-isotropic-cellular-automaton-stationary-turing-patterns-and-spiral-waves-_59b15a951723dd156022d6ab_pdf)]), as noted by Stephen Wolfram [himself](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/cellular-automata-complexity/pdfs/two-dimensional-cellular-automata.pdf) (Fig. 13c, remark on page 239), but I didn't find anyone actually modeling the magnetic domains dynamics with cellular automata. That said, magnetic domains have been shown to display features of complex systems at criticality, such as [self-organization](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.45.2192), [avalanches](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.64.2168), and [fractal geometry](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.66.014433).